# Access useState content name from string

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code in a ReactJS app:

```
this.state = {
   type1: 0,
   type2: 0,
   type3: 0
}

const setCount = (num, type) => {
   let newNum = this.state[type];

   newNum = newNum + num * (this.state[type] >= 5 ? 2 : 1);
}
```

But now I'm working in a functional component and using hooks to manage state, so my code looks like this:

```
   const [type1, setType1] = useState(0);
   const [type2, setType2] = useState(0);
   const [type3, setType3] = useState(0);

const setCount = (num, type) => {

   // Need help here
}
```

Is there any way to replicate the function in the old code to be used as simply with hooks? I'm not experienced in react with hooks, and I really don't want to make a case by case check based on "if type === 'type1'..."

Comment: you can still use the full object in one `useState({type1: 0,type2: 0,type3: 0})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try combining the three `types` into an object and use that in a single `useState` like so:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  type1: 0,
  type2: 0,
  type3: 0
});


const setCount = (num, type) => {
   let newNum = state[type];

   newNum = newNum + num * (state[type] >= 5 ? 2 : 1);
}
```

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm inexperienced with hooks and didn't think to use them this way. It helps a lot!